# How can I have a green font in *NIX's gvim?

Tags: fonts, vim

I have noted that I cannot affect MacVim's colorscheme by commands in vimrc.
I have now a gray font on black background, which makes reading hard.

Comment: Your title no longer matches the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd. What do you get after trying `":hi Normal guifg=Yellow"` ?

Comment: Thank you! Your answer suggested me to replace ctermbf and ctermfg by guibf and guifg, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I normally put all gvim related commands in .gvimrc. If you are using vi/vim, then the terminal colorscheme messes up with the vim colorscheme. If MacVim has a separate .rc file, you can check that (assuming MacVim pops a new window).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this Mac port of gvim at Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/). It lives in its own window, rather than in a terminal window, and appears to offer more (or more easy) customization of appearance.